# Html2canvas providing different result when on development server

Tags: c#, html, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

[Current pdf output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8IYF.png)My application is currently using Angular 7 where we are using html2canvas library to generate pdf for monthly report.
It works fine locally. However when pushed into development server it gives different pdf such as blank pdf, cropped pdf, expected pdf every time we generate pdf. I have tried different aspects to resolve this issue but failed. However for now I am getting the following result I have attached the image below for your reference. The pdf is getting cropped off from below.
However in backend we are currently using .Netcore if there are any possibilities for me to generate pdf from backend?
Or possibilities to send Image URL into .Netcore and generate the pdf from .Netcore and send it back to angular? or API approach?
Looking forward to guidance.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and explain what you mean when you say `it gives different pdf every time` - different **how**?

Comment: Different as in sometimes blank page sometimes cropped pdf sometimes expected result